# System of ODE's - Positivity on each coordinate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have a system of ODE's

$$x'(t)=f(x,y,t)\\y'(t)=g(x,y,t)$$

s.t. $f(0,y,t)\equiv 0$ and for an initial condition $x(0)=a>0$, $y(0)=b$ I have solution $x_1(t),y_1(t)$.

Could $x_1(t)$ be negative on some $t^*$?

I think no, because taking $x\equiv 0$ the system becomes

$$y'(t)=g(0,y,t)$$

Let $y_2(t)$ be the solution of this least equation s.t. $y_2(t^{**})=y_1(t^*)$ for some $t^{**}$. So, $x_2(t)\equiv 0, y_2(t)$ is a solution to the system and contains point $(0,y_1(t^*))=(x_1(t^*),y_1(t^*))$, contradiction.

Is it correct?

Thank  you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x,y,t)=-x^{2/3}t$ and $g(x,y,t)=0$. A solution to your system is $$x(t)=\Bigg(-\frac{t^2}{6}+a^{1/3}\Bigg)^3$$ $$y(t)=b$$ As you can see $x(t)$ will eventually assume negative values.

Comment: There is no certainty that allows the use of "eventually". $x(t)$ could stay at $x(t)=0$ indefinitely after branching in to this level.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand, so at the ODE $x'(t)=-x^{2/3}t$ I could take two solutions, $x\equiv0$ and $x(t)=\bigg(-\frac{t^2}{6}+a^{1/3}\bigg)^3$ s.t. they can cross...? Particularly, there is two solutions of IVP $x'(t)=-x^{2/3}t; x(0)=0$. Why cannot I have uniqueness here? Thank you so much.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you, sorry, and could I know when this can occur? THank you

Comment: Its because derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $x$ is not bounded on $0$, isnt... Well, right... But if in fact I have the uniqueness, so could I supose that the aim of question is valid...? Thank you so much!

Comment: Because the equation is not Lipschitz at $x=0$ you can not expect uniqueness there, and indeed you found the different solution to the same IC. There is nothing to do, the answer still remains valid, it is a solution, just not the only one for the same starting point.

Comment: And yes, with a Lipschitz condition and thus uniqueness, the argument in the question is correct, the solutions that fill the $x=0$ line (or plane in $(t,x,y)$ space) prevent any other solution from crossing it.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you so much!

Comment: @Luts Lehmann I would argue my use of the word "eventually" is appropiate since it's in direct reference to a solution I provided. You are right though that the solution I gave isn't the *only* solution which is why I changed *the* solution to *a* solution.